# artisan error while installing admin panel via composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am using `laravel 4.2` and want to install admin panel. I tried to install it from [here](https://github.com/sleeping-owl/admin/tree/laravel-4.2).
It installed complete after that i followed step 2 and 3 from that link.
And when i followed step 4 and tried this command

```
    php artisan admin:install
```

I got **error**

> there are no command defined in the 'admin' name space

Also i tried many other admin panel in `laravel 4.2`, but when i try to install it i am getting same error all time, only namespace will change.

I tried `php artisan list` and i can't find that command in list.

Comment: Can you print the contents of `php artisan list`?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `php artisan dump` - it sounds like the classes haven't be reloaded

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
php artisan optimize
```

to remove cached files and generate them again